# Why is computed property not working as v-model on Vuetify date picker?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I created a reusable component for Vuetify v-date-picker. I used props to allow setting of value from parent component to child component. Then I created a computed property in the child component for the date ranges to allow changes of props.

The v-date-picker selected the date range on first load but can't make any changes to it.

Template:

```
               <v-date-picker
                    v-model="dateRange"
                    color="green"
                    no-title
                    range
                    scrollable
                >
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn text color="primary" @click="onCancel">
                        Cancel
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn text color="primary" @click="onSave">
                        OK
                    </v-btn>
                </v-date-picker>
```

Script

```
props: {
        range: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => {
                return [
                    moment()
                        .startOf("month")
                        .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                    moment()
                        .endOf("month")
                        .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                ];
            }
        },
},
computed: {
        dateRange: {
            get() {
                return this.range;
            },
            set(value) {
                return value;
            }
        },
}
```

But the selection works if I don't use a computed property as v-model from a prop.

Template:

```
               <v-date-picker
                    v-model="dates"
                    color="green"
                    no-title
                    range
                    scrollable
                >
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn text color="primary" @click="onCancel">
                        Cancel
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn text color="primary" @click="onSave">
                        OK
                    </v-btn>
                </v-date-picker>
```

Script:

```
data() {
        return {
            dates: [
                moment()
                    .startOf("month")
                    .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                moment()
                    .endOf("month")
                    .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Did u get any error?

Comment: @MobinSamani I didn't get any error. I can't just select a range on v-date-picker if I used a computed property from prop value as v-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to make it work with *computed property*, you can do it this way:

```
  computed: {
    dateRange: {
      get() {
        return this.range
      },
      set(value) {
        this.range = value
      },
    },
  },
```

But you properly already noticed that you can just use *data property* as `v-model`, which is much simpler.

So back to the actual issue: you probably misunderstood *computed property* in Vue, *computed property* is **NOT** *data property*, it's a function that returns a value (computed/processed from other data sources), and Vue just allows you to access it like a property for convenience, which means it cannot be "set". For *computed setter* (I guess the name is bit misleading) it is a callback function when you assign a value to the *computed property*. You can find more details in the official doc: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter. If you have some Python background, just imagine it's a class function with `@property` decorator, but Vue is even nicer as the *computed property* is reactive and cached.

Comment: Thank you. It works. You're right that I misunderstood some concepts.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why can't you use a computed field *with* a setter (assuming the setter is not erroneous like in OP) as a v-model?